# Application insight - How can I make left join from request to bind with exceptions via Kusto language?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql

I have a simple question for kusto language expert for rejecting Custom values from requests and binding with an exception I am seeing these values from simple queries but in the below queries:

I have only 2 custom fields :

- source
- subject

How can I add this result? What am I missing? I made some research for an answer by googling but I didn`t find any exact answer.

```
requests
| extend source= tostring(customDimensions["source"]), orderID= tostring(customDimensions["subject"])
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where success == False
| project name, operation_Id,   StartTime=timestamp, orderID, source
| join ( exceptions
| project timestamp, problemId,type,method,outerMessage,outerMethod,innermostType,innermostMessage,severityLevel,details,customDimensions,operation_Name,operation_Id,operation_ParentId
) on operation_Id
| evaluate autocluster()
```

Comment: Please avoid tag spamming.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to achieve and how it relates to the code you provided. Please add a data sample + required results in text format/datatable and if needed give a short explanation as to the transformation logic.

Comment: Anyways, for left join use `join kind=leftjoin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used your query to reproduce. I am able to fetch the required result.

#### Workaround follows:

##### The result before Join the request and exception

[image]

[image]

##### No. of False Success Result in my AI

[image]

##### Using Join:

[image]

##### Using left join

use **join kind=leftsemi**. It returns the left which match with the right. Refer [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#returns) for join flavor to do require join operation.
[image]